# Is it possible to download macOS updates to external hard drive?

Tags: mac, external-hard-drive

My work MacBook Air (2017 MacBook Air with 120gb hard drive) has a pathetically small internal hard drive, to the point where I have to uninstall Xcode and everything else before I can update macOS.

I would be embarrassed to sell a mainstream laptop with a hard drive this small. Shameful.

I have a larger external hard drive, and I'd like to put the update on it so I can run it from there, instead of the internal hard drive.

I don't see any option to download the update outside of macOS, and no option to change where the update is saved to.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details: What is the size of the hard drive on your MacBook Air? What make and model of MacBook Air is this?

Comment: Are you trying to update - 11.1 to 11.2, or upgrade - 10.x to 11.x? Full installers [or the old-style combo updaters] can be on an external drive, but delta updaters cannot [without perhaps some symlink juggling beyond my paygrade]

Comment: @Tetsujin 12.1 to 12.3.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 It's a 2017 MacBook Air with 120gb hard drive. Most of that is filled up with the operating system, system data, and developer stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple appears to have discontinued the practice of making "delta" and "combo" updaters available on their support website starting with macOS 11 Big Sur, and so all updates after the OS **X** era are only available to download from the AppStore, Software Update System preference, and the command line utility.

If you have a second Mac with sufficient space to download and a USB drive that you are willing to erase, you might be able to create a bootable USB drive (or partition of one). Grab the installer either from the AppStore or the `softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer 12.3` (use `--list-full-installers` to find a different version), and follow the steps in this Apple Knowledge Base article: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

Possibly booting to Internet Recovery Mode might get you a full installer, but I'm not sure how it behaves with a nearly full disk. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904 "On an Intel-based Mac, … you can use **Option-Command-R** during startup to be offered either the latest macOS that is compatible with your Mac"

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a second mac. I did try to navigate in Terminal to the external hd and run the download only option of the fetch full installer, but it doesn't seem to have that much imagination.

Comment: @AndyD273 I personally enjoy the third party utility Daisy Disk for locating unwanted files and storage. Another option is Grand Perspective. Good luck, I understand the trouble of dealing with limited storage.

Comment: I just recalled recovery mode is another option, KB article linked in my edit